# Mocha Chai .end() function not being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I have been trying to write a Mocha chai test for a Nodejs API. It was previously written using Supertest. However, in both cases, the test always passed even though I specify wrong expected parameters.

Here is the test function using chai

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);


const app = require("../app");
const user = {
  first_name: "Name",
    last_name: "Lastname",
    email: "email",
    password: "password"
};

describe("Registration  Test", () => {
  it("Responds with status of registration", (done) => {
    chai.request(app)
    .post('/register')
    .send(user)
    .end((err,res) => {
      if(err) done(err);
      res.should.have.status.eq(200);
      res.body.should.have.property('success').eq(true);
      done();   <------------ Here it doesn't work. It returns For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called error
    });
    done(); <----------- But here it works

  });


});
```

The API responds with a body with properties success, message and status. But no matter what I write in the chai should checks, the test always passes. Also, when I add the done(); inside the end(), it is not being found, and but when I write it outside the end(), it runs. So I assume my code is never entering the .end().

Answer (score 1):

So, It was a silly mistake that I was doing. I had the server running manually with **npm start** and the port 5000 was occupied. When I was running the testscript using **chai.request(app)** the port was already occupied and I only realized that later. However, I wrote the script using async/await like this,

```js
describe("Tests for Doctor and Patient Registration", () => {
  it("Existing doctor registation fails", async () => {
    const res = await chai
      .request(app)
      .post("/register")
      .set("Content-type", "application/json")
      .set("Connection", "keep alive")
      .send(user[0]);

    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    expect(res.body).to.have.property("success", false);
    expect(res.body).to.have.property(
      "message",
      "A user with this email already exist, did you forget your password?"
    );
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `done` parameter and call it only inside the `end` function:

```
it("Responds with status of doctor registration", function (done) {
  chai.request(app)
    .post('/register')
    .send(user)
    .end((err,res) => {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.should.have.status.eq(200);
      res.body.should.have.property('success').eq(true);
    });
});
```

Reference https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#caveat

Comment: I did pass the done. But I get the same error that says timeout exceeded, ensure done() is called.